# Emsripten compiled qt application does not show images

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly, emscripten

I have some Qt chess application. Everything works fine when i build it using VS compiler or gcc but I have problem with web assembly version using emscripten. When i run html with emrun everything is ok but images just does not show up.

My emscripten version is emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.38.30 (commit d33f7a29002a2463a7956cd53a559b97a52f9560).

My qmake version: QMake version 3.1

My Qt version: Using Qt version 5.13.0

I am using official Qt binaries from online linux installer for wasm.

I am using emrun --no_browser .html command to set up server on localhost.

I tried different kinds of paths specification.
I ended up with this code example, works ok but not with web assembly version.
This is code to load an example image.

```
...
QDir::setSearchPaths("qrc", QStringList(":/"));
return QIcon(QUrl("qrc:///Images/king_white.svg").toString());
```

this is my .qrc file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>Images/king_black.svg</file>
    ...
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

in .pro file I also have:

```
RESOURCES = resources.qrc
```

It works okay when I am not using emscripten.
Thanks for help.

EDIT:
Build options (from Makefile generated by qmake)

```
CC            = emcc
CXX           = em++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O3 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O3 -std=gnu++1y -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I. -I../../Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/include -I../../Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/include/QtWidgets -I../../Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/include/QtGui -I../../Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/include/QtCore -I. -I/home/somas/.emscripten_ports/openssl/include -I../../Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/mkspecs/wasm-emscripten
QMAKE         = /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
QINSTALL      = /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/bin/qmake -install qinstall
QINSTALL_PROGRAM = /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = ChessNewGeneration.js1.0.0
DISTDIR = /home/somas/ChessNewGeneration/ChessNewGeneration/.tmp/ChessNewGeneration.js1.0.0
LINK          = em++
LFLAGS        = -s WASM=1 -s FULL_ES2=1 -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=0 -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=1 --bind -s "BINARYEN_TRAP_MODE='clamp'" -O3 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/platforms/libqwasm.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5EventDispatcherSupport.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libqtfreetype.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5EglSupport.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqico.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Widgets.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Gui.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libqtlibpng.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libqtharfbuzz.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libQt5Core.a /home/somas/Qt513/5.13.0/wasm_32/lib/libqtpcre2.a   
AR            = emar cqs
RANLIB        = 
SED           = sed
STRIP         =
```

Comment: What's your build command? Please post it including your all emcc compile flags.

Comment: post edited I didnt use manual build command, just qmake and then make

Comment: What does `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()` return? Did you try with `QT += svg` in your .pro file?

Comment: I didnt but it doesnt work only with emscripten so I thought it is problem with emscripten option/qt emscripten build. Anyway I will try to add it and will back with results.

Comment: @BenjaminT The `QT += svg` will link-in the `libQt5Svg.a` which is a set of additional components that are used to handle the SVG format explicitly: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-module.html . What OP actually needs is much simpler `qsvg` image format plugin which is enough to simply load and display a SVG image using standard, format-agnostic Qt API. Linking against the `libQt5Svg.a` will probably pull the respective plugin as a hard dependency (I may be wrong here) so using it may help indirectly, but it may bloat the final executable unnecessarily if the linker doesn't skip it as unused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that by "when I am not using emscripten" means the regular, dynamically-loaded Qt. Image format plugins included in such installations are dynamic libraries and can be loaded on demand by Qt - this is the mechanism used to load the svg format plugin if it is required.

The emscripten Qt builds are currently only static libraries - these must be linked together in advance as they cannot be dynamically loaded when required. In order to make qmake aware which plugins you will need, add

```
QTPLUGIN += qsvg
```

to your project file. You will probably want to make it wasm-specific to
avoid interference on other platforms:

```
wasm {
    QTPLUGIN += qsvg
}
```

Comment: it's working! I just back from holidays. Thank you for help!